# Excel-VBA/App Function: Derive Hierarchy Level from Parent/Child Data

Tags: excel, vba

I have Child in Column A and Parent in Column B. I need to derive hierarchy level to sort them. The data extract comes unsorted and I'm trying to figure out a way to achieve this through VBA or Excel App function.

```
Child       Parent
00004467    00001083
00019886    00014581
00011572    00001083
00002353    00011572
00014581    00001083
00003935    00004467
00001083    00001437
00019887    00014581
00001888    00004467
00002606    00011572
00004289    00004467
00051941    00014581
00008847    00011572
```

Expected output

```
Child       Parent      Hierarchy
00001083    00001437    1
00004467    00001083    1.1
00011572    00001083    1.2
00014581    00001083    1.3
00003935    00004467    1.1.1
00001888    00004467    1.1.2
00004289    00004467    1.1.3
00002353    00011572    1.2.1
00002606    00011572    1.2.2
00008847    00011572    1.2.3
00019886    00014581    1.3.1
00019887    00014581    1.3.2
00051941    00014581    1.3.3
```

Comment: You are correct in that you need VBA for this, and you'll probably want to write some recursive functions for this.

Comment: Thank you Sam for the quick response!  Can you refer some logic?  I started with few things in VBA but couldn't think through the logic to achieve this.

Comment: This is a typical example of a recursive tree walk. There is plenty of material describing explaining this on the net. In short - write a function that calls itself. A hint to get you started: Sub WalkTree(ParentID As String, Path As String)